# How can I use the curl C library on Fedora?

Tags: c, libcurl, fedora

When I try to compile a C file containing `#include <curl/curl.h>` I get the following error: `Error: curl/curl.h: no such file or directory`.

I have the curl package installed.

Do I need to specify some command line argument to use it? Or install some other package?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the libcurl-devel package. From command line: `sudo dnf install libcurl-devel`.

Then you need to set the -lcurl option when compiling the file. For instance, using clang: `clang <c_file> -lcurl -o <executable>`

Comment: The `-lcurl` is needed when linking the executable.  If you compile to an object file first, you don't need `-lcurl` while creating the object file.  You might or might not need to specify the directory where the headers for `libcurl` are found (`-I/opt/libcurl/include` or something like that).  However, with a package install of `libcurl-devel`, you probably won't need to do that.

Comment: You can get required flags from pkgconf separately: `pkgconf -cflags libcurl` for compilation and `pkgconf -libs libcurl` for linking.